# Machine Guns or Cannons?

Tags: defense-grid-awakening

Which is more effective? Guns or Cannons?

Fully upgraded, a Cannon has a bigger range, and a higher damage output than a Machine Gun, but a Machine Gun has the max rate of fire, while the Cannon is only sitting just under half.

So which is better?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Yes.

Sorry, got a bit glib there.

A longer answer, then: They are both highly effective against different enemy types, and much less effective against some others.

Cannons, with their much longer range and heavier shells, are *excellent* at cracking those big, heavily armored slow-moving targets, but their slow rate of fire and single shot makes them of limited use against large numbers of smaller opponents.

Gun towers, on the other hand, are your basic Jack-of-all-trades. They're decent against a wide range of different enemy types, although limited in range and not the actual best against any one type. They're not as devastating to swarms of small critters as Flame towers, they don't have the range or burst damage of Cannon or Missile towers, they don't have the AoE to splatter groups like the Meteor towers do...

**But...**

- The Flame tower can't hit airborne targets at all...
- ... The Cannon tower has a very slow rate of fire and can't hit targets right next to it...
- ... The missile tower can only hit air targets (this is changed in 2)...
- ... The Tesla tower takes a long time to recharge after a single burst discharge...
- ... The Laser Tower relies on the targets collapsing from heat damage over time...
- ... And the Meteor and Concussion towers cost more than four times as much to build, and neither of them can target air units.

Gun towers are decent at all jobs and very cheap, which is a crucially important criteria early on when you need to plunk down towers quickly to shape the enemy path, and later on a fully upgraded gun tower will put a serious dent into anything that tries to get through its field of fire.